# Entity Framework 6 Code First approach - unique constraint doesn't work

Tags: database, entity-framework, validation, entity-framework-6

I am using EF 6 with code first approach. In addition to database constraints check at database level, I would like to provide unique constraints check at POCO level. I have followed article [Setting unique Constraint with fluent API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21573550/entity-framework-6-setting-unique-constraint-with-fluent-api) where someone suggested to use [Index()] attribute. **I have applied the same in my poco class but looks like it is still throwing an exception from Database level.**

Here is my code:

```cs
[Key]
public decimal OrderId { get; set; }

[Index("ORDER_CC", 2, IsUnique = true)]
public decimal? MemberId { get; set; }

[Index("ORDER_CC", 3, IsUnique = true)]
public decimal? ItemId { get; set; }

[Index("ORDER_CC", 1, IsUnique = true)]
public decimal? OrderNumber { get; set; }

public decimal? Cost { get; set; }

public DateTime Time { get; set; }
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here?

**I also want to ask followings:**

1. Do I need to keep the same index name as the one I have on my database table for Order?
2. How do I know, it is getting validate against EF constraints check or Database constraints check?
3. I have kept the same order for index on POCO class compare to one defined in Order table in database.

Here is my Database script:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX xyz.ORDER_CC ON xyz.Order
(OrderNumber, MemberId, ItemId)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE USERS
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          128K
            NEXT             1M
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
            FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
            CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
           )
NOPARALLEL;
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in the Index attribute, it's in your expectations of what it does.

**The Index attribute doesn't validate a unique constraint**, it only instructs Entity Framework code-first to [create an index in the database during a migration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Index). From your questions it is clear that you use EF code-first, i.e. POCO's and coded mappings, but you work with a preexisting database. In this case, applying index attributes is useless.

So that also answers your question where the constraint is checked: in the database. And that's why it's still throwing errors. If you want a unique constraint in code you'll have to write it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, we have existing database. You said "If you want a unique constraint in code you'll have to write it yourself" - How do I achieve this? Do you mean to provide this check in POCO classes? I am just new to POCO and EF. Thanks

Comment: Also, we want to provide unique constraint check in POCO (We don't have it) as well as in Database (we have it in DB). THanks

Comment: Not necessarily in the class (the entity) itself, but in the code where the entity is stored. Like, when a name should be unique you check whether it exists right before saving changes. Not really fancy about it. The database constraint is the final catch in case heavy concurrency squeezes itself between checking and saving.

Answer (score 0):

### ***Update***

**I have posted about this at [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1143215/Validate-a-Unique-Constraint-at-dbContext-Validate)**

In general, it depends on the attributes that you put on the classes to generate your unique indexes

---

Thanks to Shimmy in this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15999805/105445

You can do it yourself by **creating a custom `ValidationAttribute`** to validate the property in a generic way. Then you can use it like this:

```
[ShouldBeUnique()]
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

Take a look at this example

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shimmy/2012/01/23/uniqueattribute-that-validates-a-unique-field-against-its-fellow-rows-in-the-database-inherits-dataannotationsvalidationattribute/