# Validate Unique Value in MVC5 and EF6

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, unique

In my MVC application I have a requirement where I want user to insert Unique value in a column.

i.e.: `Username` should be unique in `Users` table.

I used `[Indes(IsUnique = true)]` data annotation in my model.

But when I insert duplicate value in the field it throws an exception, but I want to display an Error Message on my View saying **Please try with a different Username**

Please help me what should I do here?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29421572/861716

Comment: Yes, it is almost similar to what you linked, but how can I achive this.

Should I validate it implicitly in my business layer or is there any default functionality to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of those:

1. Write your CustomValidator (ny recommendation)

   ```
   [CustomRemoteValidator(ErrorMessage = @"Username already in use")]
   public string Username{ get; set; }`
   ```

   And override IsValid method

   ```
   public override bool IsValid(object value)
   {
       return !(this.DbContext.Set<User>().Any(a => 
           a.Username.Equals((string)value));
   }
   ```
2. Check it in your business layer.
3. Check it before save entity in database by overriding `SaveChanges()` method.